# Disable Apple Pay UI when 13.56Mhz detection

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, applepay

I am aware that there is specific [new method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PKPassLibrary_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/PKPassLibrary/requestAutomaticPassPresentationSuppressionWithResponseHandler:) in iOS 9 that supports Apple Pay suppression for specific scenarios or use cases. I have one of those who need to be applied with the following method:

```
+ (PKSuppressionRequestToken)requestAutomaticPassPresentationSuppressionWithResponseHandler:(void (^ _Nonnull)(PKAutomaticPassPresentationSuppressionResult result))responseHandler
```

However, every time we call this method we get the following response: `PKAutomaticPassPresentationSuppressionResultDenied (Either the user prevented the suppression, or an internal error occurred)`

In the documentation marks as an importante note that:

> IMPORTANT 
>   This method requires a special entitlement issued by Apple.
>   If the entitlement is not present, the request will fail with a
>   PKAutomaticPassPresentationSuppressionResultNotSupported result. For
>   more information, see developer.apple.com/apple-pay/.

What should we do in order to get the `PKAutomaticPassPresentationSuppressionResultSuccess` result? We have enabled the Apple Pay in our "Apple ID" and even created a Merchand ID, after that downloaded again the Development Provisioning Profile which includes all this and included in the project. There as well we enabled the "Apple Pay" capability but we still get the `PKAutomaticPassPresentationSuppressionResultDenied` error.

Testing environment Information:

- iPhone 6 with an Apple Pay enabled card
- iOS 9.0.1 (13A404)

Thanks for all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After opening a private query to the Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS) they told me I had to request a specific entitlement for this purpose via email. In that email I had to justify why should I use this PassKit functionality and how would it be utilized.

Once they made this entitlement available (after some weeks) it was just enough to add it to our provisioning profiles and the `requestAutomaticPassPresentationSuppressionWithResponseHandler` method would work without any problem.

Comment: How can i reach you privately? I'd like to know more detail.